# Will my custom token increase the number of unit after deployed the contract?

Tags: contract-deployment, miner

I follow the [example here](https://www.ethereum.org/token), I can input an *initial supply*, let say `1,000,000` is my initial supply.

After 1 or 2 years, the miner mine, will the total number of token increased to `1,000,xxx`?

Comment: The tokens aren't mined you determine in your contract the total supply.

Comment: @BadrBellaj Do you mean that once I set the initial supply to `1,000,000`, then forever the total supply will be `1,000,000` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, there are two different terms initial supply and total supply. 
Initial Supply is the number of coins you put into owner's account at point of contract deployment by using code: `balanceOf[owner] = initialSupply;`.

As per the [code here](https://www.ethereum.org/token#full-coin-code). Total Supply keeps on increasing (every time you call Mint function) while Initial Supply is fixed.

However, if you want a fixed total Supply, you will increase `currentSupply` every time new coins are generated(either by Minting or PoW) and check whether the `currentSupply` is less than `totalSupply` every time new coins are generated.

Sample code for Mint token function:

```
function mintToken(address target, uint256 mintedAmount) onlyOwner {
            if(currentSupply + mintedAmount> totalSupply) throw;             // check for total supply.
            currentSupply+=(mintedAmount);                                   //updating currentSupply.
            balanceOf[target] += mintedAmount;                               //adding balance to recipient.
            Transfer(0, owner, mintedAmount);
            Transfer(owner, target, mintedAmount);
    }
```

PS: Correct me If I am wrong.

**Edit:**
DOn't confuse owner with who owns what percentage of coin. Owner is just an address who has write to call some functions that can not be called by other accounts like `Mint`. You specify owner as:

```
function owned() {
  owner = msg.sender;
}
modifier onlyOwner {
  if (msg.sender != owner) throw;
   _;
}
function transferOwnership(address newOwner) onlyOwner {
   owner = newOwner;
}
```

In this case, the address from which contract is deployed is the owner. 
You can change **owner** by calling `transferOwnership` function. You can use modifier `onlyOwner` for a function if you want that only owner of the contract can call these functions( like `transferOwnership`).

Comment: That means if I'm the owner, then I can anytime increase the `totalSupply`? Out of no where?

Comment: Exactly. The mint functions basically produce new coins to someone's account. Don't forget the onlyOwner modifier function for this function else anybody can call the function to produce coins.

Comment: Let say if I hold 49% of total coin, am I still consider as **Owner**?

Comment: The owner has nothing to do with shares of the token. Check Edits.